# Cursor returning incorrect values

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I am creating an application for monitoring personal finances. The user creates accounts, categories and transactions. The `dBHelper.java` class creates the database as shown below:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //executes only once
    //create tables
    Log.v("TAG", "creating table:" +racuniTable);
    String sql = "create table " +racuniTable+" (" +colID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
    +colName+ " TEXT, " +colValue+ " REAL, " +colAccType+ " TEXT);";

    Log.v("TAG", "creating table:" +transakcijeTable);
    String sql1 = "create table " +transakcijeTable+" (" +colTransID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
    +colTransDate+ " DATE, "  +colAmount+ " REAL, " 
    +colIDracuni+ " INTEGER, " +colIDkategorije+ " INTEGER);";

    Log.v("TAG", "creating table:" +kategorijeTable);
    String sql2 = "create table " +kategorijeTable+" (" +colCatID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +colCatName+ " TEXT);";
    Log.v("TAG", "adding account:");

    db.execSQL(sql);
    db.execSQL(sql1);
    db.execSQL(sql2);
}
```

This function create the three databases. The problem occurs when I try to get the list of all the transactions or any other report configured by the SQL sentence:

```
private void getTransactions(){

    try {
        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
        m_transaction = new ArrayList<transaction>();
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT rac.Ime, trans.Znesek, trans.Datum,   kate.Ime FROM Racuni AS rac, " + "Transakcije AS trans, Kategorije 
        as kate WHERE trans.ID_racuna=rac._id AND trans.ID_kategorije=kate._id", null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String racun = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("rac.Ime"));
                    double znesek = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("trans.Znesek"));
                    String datum = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("trans.Datum"));
                    String kategorija = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("kate.Ime"));

                    transaction t1 = new transaction();
                    t1.setracun(racun);
                    t1.setznesek(znesek);
                    t1.setdatum(datum);
                    t1.setkategorija(kategorija);   

                    m_transaction.add(t1);

                }while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }       
    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
  }
```

I used a `Cursor` to show the list of accounts before and it worked perfect. I don't know why it isn't working anymore. I didn't use foreign keys in the tables or anything like that and it should be working. If I execute the code I will get the wrong values and plenty of errors. I get the errors on these specific lines:

```
String racun = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("rac.Ime"));
double znesek = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("trans.Znesek"));
String datum = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("trans.Datum"));
String kategorija = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("kate.Ime"));
```

The application will run and I will get the information printed. All of the information printed is correct. The string `racun` is same as the string `kategorija` when they shouldn't be. I am unsure on why I keep getting the wrong values from the `racun` column. I tested my SQL using SQLite 3 with the `adb` shell and it was working fine. Here are the errors from the LogCat:

```
08-19 17:48:16.279: ERROR/Cursor(625): requesting column name with table name -- rac.Ime

08-19 17:48:16.331: ERROR/Cursor(625): requesting column name with table name -- trans.Znesek

08-19 17:48:16.359: ERROR/Cursor(625): requesting column name with table name -- trans.Datum

08-19 17:48:16.439: ERROR/Cursor(625): requesting column name with table name -- kate.Ime
```

Is there something wrong because I used the alias in SQL? This is should be printed:

```
SELECT rac.Ime, trans.Znesek, trans.Datum, kate.Ime FROM Racuni AS rac, Transakcije AS trans, Kategorije as kate WHERE trans.ID_racuna=rac._id AND trans.ID_kate
    gorije=kate._id;
    Tomaz|50.0|3911-08-18|placa
    Tom|33.0|3912-07-18|placa
    Tomaz|70.0|3800-07-17|zapravlanje
    Tom|69.0|2010-07-17|placa
    Tomaz|30.0|2011-08-18|placa
    Tom|30.0|2011-08-12|zapravlanje
    Tom|50.0|2011-08-01|placa
    sqlite>
```

[This](http://www.shrani.si/f/3P/MR/3JeBXndJ/screenshot391.jpg) was the rest I received. Any suggestions in how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
SELECT rac.Ime, trans.Znesek, trans.Datum, kate.Ime FROM ...
```

to:

```
SELECT rac.Ime racun, trans.Znesek, trans.Datum, kate.Ime kategorja FROM ...
```

and then change respectively

```
c.getColumnIndex(...)
```

Comment: It works! Now it seems so easy, but I was smashing my head in the wall for too many hours, because of this. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. If you had used `.headers on` in sqlite3 console you would have seen that you have two columns `Ime` in results :)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

**Table_1: id, name,details**

### **Table_2: id, name,price**

```
String ALL_COLUMNS_TABLE_2="Table_2.id _id, Table_2.name _name, Table_2.price _price";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select "+ Table_1 +".*,"+ALL_COLUMNS_TABLE_2+" from " + Table_1 + "," + Table_2,null);
try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

                    int idTable1 = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("id"));
int idTable2 = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("_id"));
....
}
```